# function mapping delphi/pascal dll in jna handle and string

Tags: java, delphi, dll, parameters, jna

I'm trying to call a function in a delphi dll using [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access). the function definition is:

```
function myFuncGetName (aHandle : THandle; var aBuf : pwideChar ): integer; export;
```

my jna mapping looks like this:

```
int myFuncGetName(PointerByReference aHandle, WString aBuf);
```

the return value should be 0 for success and -1 for fail and I'm always getting -1.

I have started up WinDbg and attached to the process and it breaks at myFuncGetName.

```
057cb384 eb11            jmp     myDLL!myFuncGetName+0x87 (057cb397)
057cb386 b8dcb37c05      mov     eax,offset myDLL!myFuncGetName+0xcc (057cb3dc)
057cb38b 8b55f8          mov     edx,dword ptr [ebp-8]
057cb38e 8902            mov     dword ptr [edx],eax  ds:002b:00000000=???????? <-- ### breaks here ###
057cb390 c745f4ffffffff  mov     dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],0FFFFFFFFh
```

I'm not an assembly wiz so correct me where I'm wrong. 
I think its moving an address (function argument) from location ebp-8 to the edx register. 
ebp-8 points to value 0 so edx is 0. 
it moves eax to address pointed by edx. 
Its not supposed to move anything to 0 so it all breaks?

Why aren't my arguments correctly passed to the function? 
I get aHandle from the same DLL from a previous call and I set up aBuf as 
WString aBuf = new WString("placeholderstring");
I expect aBuf to be filled with real text after the function returns.

This is all running on Windows 7 with java 7 64bit. The DLL is a 32bit DLL.

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION:**

Thank you David and Rob for your comments. I have changed the delphi definition to use the stdcall declaration. Calling the function now returns 0 which it should. To retrieve the value of the pwideChar I did the following:

```
int charcount= "placeholder".length();
PointerByReference aBuf = new PointerByReference(new Memory(charcount*4));
int returnvalue = myFuncGetName(aHandle, aBuf);
if(returnvalue == 0) {
    System.out.println(aBuf.getValue().getString(0, true));
}
```

Comment: If that's really the machine code, then only the first line is relevant. It jumps past the four subsequent lines to address 057cb397. Please show more.

Comment: you're right, didn't see that, there must be something happening to jump that statement as well or the entry point is below it? because the debugger breaks on the second to last line. I just edited it again to make it clearer where the debugger breaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's the real declaration of the DLL function, then the problem could be the calling convention. The default calling convention in Delphi is `register`, which stores the first two arguments in EAX and EDX, but the default C calling convention is `cdecl`, which stores them on the stack. Change the Delphi declaration to this:

```
function myFuncGetName(aHandle: THandle; var aBuf: PWideChar): Integer; stdcall;
```

(The `export` directive doesn't really do anything anymore (as of Delphi 2, I think), so you can remove it. It's been subsumed by the `exports` clause, which you should find elsewhere in the DLL source.)

The Java side is also wrong. The second parameter in the Delphi code is a *reference* to a `PWideChar`. I see no `WStringByReference` type in JNA, but that's what you'll need. I can't offer any advice on how to implement it yourself, though.

Comment: No cdecl in JNA. The conclusion in final paragraph is not necessarily correct. Yes the Java side could be wrong, but so could the Delphi side. Since the asker most likely knows Java, I bet it's the latter. In which case the signature would be as per param 2 in my answer.

Comment: @David, the existence of `Library` and its descendant `StdCallLibrary` seem to indicate that Java can call functions of either convention. The Java code is wrong in the context of the information given in the question, which states that the DLL function takes a PWideChar by reference. If the DLL is wrong, that's in the context of the specifications laid out for the operation of the DLL, which we have no information about. I'm trying to treat the DLL is a given, and it's the Java programmer's job to consume it. The bad convention must be fixed DLL-side; the type could be fixed Java-side.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use stdcall calling convention, and the string parameter is declared incorrectly (I think). The export keyword is no longer used and can be omitted. You name your exports with the exports keyword, somewhere else in your library code.

Your Delphi function should be like this.

```
function myFuncGetName(aHandle: THandle; aBuf: pwideChar): integer; stdcall;
```

I'm not sure about PointerByReference. If that is equivalent to void**, why are you mapping it to THandle?

Comment: You're right, PointerByReference is wrong. int works just fine. I had it in there because I was testing why things weren't working and it was declared as Cardinal in Delphi which is an unsigned int so I thought it would cause problems in Java. I thought my handle was incorrect at some point.

Comment: I'm sorry my answer wasn't helpful to you